# dynamically load pictures into swipebox

Tags: jquery, arrays, lightbox

I have a json array of image names that is loaded dynamically when an object is clicked. The json looks something like this:

```
{"pics":[{"picName":"289_1.jpg"},{"picName":"289_2.jpg"}]}
```

I'm trying to put them into [swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/)

```
      var lb=[];
      for(var i=0;i<=json.pics.length-1;i++){               
            lb.push( { href:'../epics/'+json.pics[i].picName } );
      } 

      $.swipebox({ lb });
```

Literally nothing happens that I can see and no errors are thrown in the console. I've got to be missing something.

Comment: must be errors thrown  ,  can't stick an array in middle of an object that has no property key ...  `$.swipebox({ lb });`

Comment: Try `$.swipebox( lb );`

Comment: that was it! thanks. Make it an "answer" and I'll give you best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect

Try:

```
$.swipebox( lb );
```